# How can I get succinct, legible XML output for F# serialization?

Tags: xml, serialization, f#

Here's my program -

```ml
module Program
open System
open System.IO
open System.Text  
open System.Xml
open System.Xml.Serialization
open System.Runtime.Serialization
open System.Reflection
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let getUnionTypes<'a> () =
    let nestedTypes = typedefof<'a>.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic) 
    Array.filter FSharpType.IsUnion nestedTypes

type Alpha =
    { X : int * int
      Y : Alpha option }

type [<KnownType "GetTypes">] Beta =
    | A of int * Alpha
    | B of Beta option
    | C of Map<int, Beta>
    static member GetTypes () = getUnionTypes<Beta> ()

let [<EntryPoint>] main _ =
    let alpha = { X = (0, 0); Y = Some { X = (1, 1); Y = None }}
    let betaA = A (0, alpha)
    let betaB = B (Some betaA)
    let betaC = C (Map.singleton 0 betaB)
    let sb = new StringBuilder()
    let xmlSerializer = DataContractSerializer(typeof<Beta>); 
    xmlSerializer.WriteObject(new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)), betaC)
    let sr = sb.ToString()
    printfn "%A" sr
    0
```

Here's the output -

```xml
"<Program.Beta xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" i:type="Progr
am.Beta.C" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/"><item xmlns:d2p1="ht
tp://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.FSharp.Collections"><d2p1:serial
izedData xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.
Generic"><d3p1:KeyValuePairOfintProgram.BetalLTIrbuF><d3p1:key>0</d3p1:key><d3p1
:value i:type="Program.Beta.B"><item xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org
/2004/07/Microsoft.FSharp.Core"><d6p1:value i:type="Program.Beta.A"><item1>0</it
em1><item2><X_x0040_ xmlns:d9p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"
><d9p1:m_Item1>0</d9p1:m_Item1><d9p1:m_Item2>0</d9p1:m_Item2></X_x0040_><Y_x0040
_><d6p1:value><X_x0040_ xmlns:d11p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sys
tem"><d11p1:m_Item1>1</d11p1:m_Item1><d11p1:m_Item2>1</d11p1:m_Item2></X_x0040_>
<Y_x0040_ i:nil="true" /></d6p1:value></Y_x0040_></item2></d6p1:value></item></d
3p1:value></d3p1:KeyValuePairOfintProgram.BetalLTIrbuF></d2p1:serializedData></i
tem></Program.Beta>"
```

What simple things might I do to improve this XML output? I tried various attributes, but none of them seemed to help. Note that I need to keep my data structures immutable, and that I would like to avoid writing my own serialization library, or add a dependency to another homebrew one if possible. It should ideally be a simple solution.

Comment: Don't use discriminated unions

Answer (score 1):

> What simple things might I do to improve this XML output?

.NET has awful support for serialization, taking a long time to generate hugely verbose message that are brittle. I would strongly advise against using it.

I wrote a (non-free) [article about XML serialization in F#](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/xml-serialization.html). I used reflection to destructure arbitrary values of F# types and convert them into XML and back again. Performance is much better than the built in serializers and the conversion is structural rather than nominal so you can read back into an identical type definition (e.g. using F# interactive) but it is still much slower than competitors like OCaml's built-in serialization. With the code from that article you just do:

```
> serialize betaC;;
val it : string =
  "<unionCase><name>C</name><map><keyValue><int>0</int><unionCase><name>B</name><unionCase><name>Some</name><unionCase><name>A</name><int>0</int><record><field><name>X</name><value><tuple><int>0</int><int>0</int></tuple></value></field><field><name>Y</name><value><unionCase><name>Some</name><record><field><name>X</name><value><tuple><int>1</int><int>1</int></tuple></value></field><field><name>Y</name><value><unionCase><name>None</name></unionCase></value></field></record></unionCase></value></field></record></unionCase></unionCase></unionCase></keyValue></map></unionCase>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pretty-print the resulting string after serialization:

```
XDocument.Parse(sr).ToString()
```

This sits in the `System.Xml.Linq` assembly and namespace.

Comment: I think the issue is that the XML appears to contain a large amount of unnecersary cruft, rather than a lack of pretty printing

Comment: If so, then implementing IXmlSerializable and hand-serializing might be the most flexible way and using pattern-matching would still make it pretty succinct

Comment: John is correct; the issue is the amount of useless, redundant text cruft in the output.